# How to use cloud-init on an RPi?

Tags: boot

I see that Raspbian currently has cloud-init 0.7.9 in its Stretch repo. If that were the latest stable version (or at least 17.1) I would have a lot more [NoCloud options](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/datasources/nocloud.html).

So, how can I use cloud-init on an RPi?

Any idea how to install from source?

Comment: Making progress! https://stackoverflow.com/a/48845732/117471